# Error when trying to log in with Auth0 in Cypress tests

Tags: javascript, authentication, xmlhttprequest, auth0, cypress

Our application is only accessible to authenticated users and we use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for the authentication.

We have started writing Cypress tests and we try to log in using Auth0 JavaScript client before each test. The first test always passes without any problems but all other tests fail with the following error:

> NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://ourdomain.eu.auth0.com/co/authenticate': Document is already detached.

Do we need to make all API calls manually using `cy.request()` in order to prevent such errors or is there any way how to make Auth0 client work?

Comment: Cypress clears your local storage every time it runs a test, your access token is probably in local storage for the first test and then it gets removed on the 2nd test. Not sure if this is your problem, but I use Auth0 and Cypress also and I had to store off the access token when I logged in and I cached it and I reset it on every test in a beforeEach Block. I don't remember getting your error. I will go look at my code to see. I did not make this an answer because I was not sure I ever got your issue.

Comment: @Maccurt, thanks but we were logging in before each test and the second request always failed with the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with Auth0, but I don't remember getting the error you are getting. In a before block I log in. I call this method in a before() block. Not sure this will help you but it was worth a shot. There should be a better way of doing it and I tried calling their API to do it, but I could never get it to work.. so I hacked this up

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginAuth0', () => {
    cy.visit('');
    cy.get('#log-in').click();
    cy.get('[type="email"]').type('MYEMAIL@DOMAIN>COM');
    cy.get('[type="password"]').type('MYPASSWORD');
    cy.get('.auth0-label-submit').click();
    cy.url().should('include', '/callback');
})
```

in a beforeEach() block I call this method

```
var accessToken = null; ** this is a global variable at top of file
Cypress.Commands.add('resetLocalStorage', () => {
    if (!accessToken) {
        accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);

}
```

in my cypress.json file I turn off chromeWebSecurity

```
"chromeWebSecurity": false
```

My spec file you will see something like this

```
 before(() => {
        cy.loginAuth0();
        cy.wait(2000); 
    })    

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.resetLocalStorage();
    })
```

Comment: I have made it work by storing the access token in the window object and then restoring it before each test (instead of logging in again). It works fine but I am still curious what causes the error when I try to log in before each test.

Comment: Don't forget about the closing bracket for the called method :)