# Cypress 10 Angular 14 Chrome & Electron Error Login Required

Tags: angular, cypress, keycloak

After upgrading Cypress to v.11.10.0 tests fail in a very early stage.

We are using keycloak for login and cypress-kecloak-commands for the tests.

Test suite works as follows:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.clearCookies();
    cy.kcLogout();
    cy.kcLogin('admin');
});
```

```
it('navigation should be displayed completely', () => {
    cy.visit('/');
    // some assertions

});
```

cy.visit('/') - as expected - redirects to http://localhost:4200/tenant-id/domain but there is an additional suffix to the url "&error=login_required&state=some-unique-id".
Apparently we are not logged in (as the login page is displayed) and the assertions after cy.visit('/') fail. It is as if the Angular web application does not "know" that it is logged in.

The tests succeed only for Firefox browser and fail for Chrome and Electron.

The tests all work quite good for electron browser if we return to Cypress version 8.7.0 where we were in before.

Cypress: v.10.11.0
Angular: v14.2.2
OS: macOS Monterey (12.5.1)

package.json devDependencies (partially):

```
"cypress": "10.11.0",
"cypress-keycloak-commands": "1.2.0",
"cypress-plugin-tab": "1.0.5",
```

cypress.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
  screenshotsFolder: 'cypress/screenshots',
  videosFolder: 'cypress/videos',
  downloadsFolder: 'cypress/downloads',
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 6000,
  apiUrl: 'http://api.develop.my-company.xy',
  viewportWidth: 1600,
  viewportHeight: 900,
  video: false,
  env: {
    login_url: 'http://login.develop.my-company.xy',
    username: 'p7s1-admin',
    password: '12345',
    api_url: 'http://api.develop.my-company.xy',
    auth_base_url: 'http://login.develop.my-company.xy/auth',
    auth_realm: 'my-company-xy',
    auth_client_id: 'booking-gui',
  },
  retries: {
    runMode: 2,
    openMode: 0,
  },
  e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/tests/**/*.{spec.js,feature,features}',
    baseUrl: 'http://my.develop.my-company.xy/en/',
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
  },
})
```

Using cy.session() on login did not help.

chromeWebSecurity is already set to FALSE.

From [Error when trying to log in with Auth0 in Cypress tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460439/error-when-trying-to-log-in-with-auth0-in-cypress-tests):
resetting local storage like this:

```
let accessToken = null; // this is a global variable at top of file
Cypress.Commands.add('resetLocalStorage', () => {
    if (!accessToken) {
        accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);

});
```

did not help either.

Comment: `cypress-keycloak-commands` has not been updated since March 2020. Cypress version 10.0.0 was released in June 2022. It would not surprise me if these are not compatible, considering the substantial changes that occurred in Cypress 10 (and 9).

Comment: true - cypress-keycloak-command seems outdated.

What are the alternatives?

There seems only https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak.

This is working even worse as also firefox is not working.

There the latest version is pushed 2 months ago, but support seems to be poor. Open issues seem not to be responded: https://github.com/babangsund/cypress-keycloak/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem.

We needed to move away from `cypress-keycloak-commands` because it's no longer supported (and doesn't play nicely with Chrome), so I looked at `cypress-keycloak`. I didn't have any joy there, so I ended up creating commands to login via the UI, and logout via the API.

## Login - commands.js

```
    Cypress.Commands.add('keycloak_login_via_ui_isolated', (user) => {
      const config = Cypress.config();

      cy.log('Loading UI home page at ' + `${config.uiAppUrl}`)
        // We're not authenticated so this causes the app to redirect to the KC login page
        .visit(`${config.uiAppUrl}`)
        // We use this (experimental) feature to ensure KC doesn't deny us entry because we're dealing with two origins (the UI app domain and the KC domain)
        .origin(config.security.keycloak.authServerUrl, { args: { user } }, function ({ user }) {
          cy.log(user);
          cy.get("#username")
            .type(user.username);
          cy.get("#password")
            .type(user.password);
          cy.get("[type=submit]")
            .click();
        });

      cy.origin(`${config.uiAppUrl}`, () => {
      });
    });
```

## Logout - commands.js

```
    Cypress.Commands.add('keycloak_logout_via_api_isolated', () => {
      const config = Cypress.config();

      cy.log('Logging out')
        .visit({
          url: config.security.keycloak.authServerUrl
            + '/auth/realms/'
            + config.security.keycloak.realm
            + '/protocol/openid-connect/logout',
          qs: {
            redirect_uri: config.uiAppUrl
          }
        });
    });
```

## cypress.config.ts

Include `experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue which has been posted recently and which might be related to mine:
[Timed out retrying after 4000ms: The command was expected to run against origin https://google.com but the application is at origin https://google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917253/timed-out-retrying-after-4000ms-the-command-was-expected-to-run-against-origin)

Similar to that issue in our case, if

- we use cypress-keycloak instead of cypress-keycloak-commands then we receive an error message like this:
- and we use Firefox

then we run into the following error message:
The command was expected to run against origin http://localhost:4200 but the application is at origin http://login.develop.my-company.xy.
This indicates that the login is not recognized by the application.

User @yash which posted the issue above solved his problem by copying the token out of the Application-section of the developer tools and writing it into local storage like this:

```
cy.visit("---your-website-url---", {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    win.localStorage.setItem(
      "token",
      "---token-here---"
    );
  },
});
```

I dont know which token to paste there. It also makes not much sense to me to paste hard coded the token there as it is newly generated in each login request.

But essentially i think we are running here into a related issue.